# Blutooth connection fails on Window 7

Tags: bluetooth, window, msdn

I am trying to connect bluetooth handset device from windows 7 and above  using below link

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296

Windows 10 is succesfuuly able to pair and connect the device but on window 7, device is only paired, socket connect is always failed  with error code 10060.

we are using Blietooth API "BluetoothFindFirstDevice" and "BluetoothFindNextDevice" to scan devices and "BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx" for sending  authentication request to a remote Bluetooth device. On window 7 bluetooth devices shows the handset under paired devices. but socket connect fails.

Does connecting to Blutooth device on window 7 using below API is possible?
 I am trying to connect bluetooth handset device from windows 7 and above  using below link

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296

Windows 10 is succesfuuly able to pair and connect the device but on window 7, device is only paired, socket connect is always failed  with error code 10060.

we are using Blietooth API "BluetoothFindFirstDevice" and "BluetoothFindNextDevice" to scan devices and "BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx" for sending  authentication request to a remote Bluetooth device. on window 7 bluetooth devices shows the handset under paired devices. but socket connect fails.

Does connecting to Blutooth device on window 7 is possible using above API,s.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc766819(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try to update your bluetooth driver.

Comment: Drivers are updated , as i am able to connect Bluetooth manually. Connect error only come when ever i try to connect through code using socket connect API.